# Adding a custom key in Symfony 2 in-memory user provider?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.4

How to add a custom key in Symfony 2 in-memory user provider?

```
providers:
    administrators:
        memory:
            users:
                admin: { password: admin, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
```

If I modify the above adding an `image` property the **user isn't able to login anymore**. Really a strange issue.

```
providers:
    administrators:
        memory:
            users:
                admin: { password: admin, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ], image: "img/plh.png" }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason is on Error log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException' with message 'Unrecognized options "image" under "security.providers.in_memory.memory.users.manage"' in ~/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/ArrayNode.php:306
```

Check: 
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php#L562

To fix it, you could extend Configuration of the SecurityBundle:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/prepend_extension.html

Comment: Very good find, thanks. I was looking for a quick solution and extending the configuration seems overkill at the moment.

Comment: @gremo A simple solution would be to add a custom ROLE that you can map back to the image path